# Getting OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: certificate verify failed - event with latest ca bundle

Tags: ruby, ssl, mechanize

Trying to access: https://www.goodbuyauto.it using ruby Mechanize:

```
m = Mecanize.new
m.ca_file="./cacert.pem"
m.get("https://www.goodbuyauto.it/")
#=> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

PS. I downloaded the latest ca file from here: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem caused by the wrong setup of the target site. As can be seen from the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.goodbuyauto.it&latest) it is missing chain certificates:

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.

Desktop browsers often work around this problem by using cached certificates or by downloading it from an external site. But outside of desktop browsers this kind of misconfiguration usually results in the error you see.

It might help to add the missing chain certificate (RapidSSL SHA256 CA) to your trust store. You might extract it from the certificate view in the browser.

Comment: Wohoooo, what a great answer! I extracted the cert using Firefox and added it to the file! Thanks again! :-D

Comment: Hi, again. Now I have another website which seems to have the same issue. Embarrassing I can't recall how I found and extracted the right certificate to add to the trusted list. Can you guide me? https://www.auto-roeder.de/

Comment: @NielsKristian: use SSLabs as shown in my answer to analyze the site. In the section for the certificate path you'll find links (as icons) which let you download the certificate chain.